# I can't get BottomNavigationBar fully Transparent in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I did background color to transparent.
Did elevation to 0
Did extend body to true but it only transparents only the background image and when i scroll the image is static not scrolling

```
Future main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(InitialScreen());

}

class InitialScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  InitialScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(

        home:

            // HomeScreen(), title: appName);

            MyBottomNavigationBar(),

        title: appName);

  }

}

class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {

  const MyBottomNavigationBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override

  State<MyBottomNavigationBar> createState() => _MyBottomNavigationBarState();

}

class _MyBottomNavigationBarState extends State<MyBottomNavigationBar> {

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _children = [

    HomeScreen(),

    MyMusic(),

    MusicQueue(),

    MyProfile(),

  ];

  void onTappedBar(int index) by {

    setState(() {

      _currentIndex = index;

    });

  }

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      endDrawerEnableOpenDragGesture: true,

      extendBody: true,

      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,

      body: _children[_currentIndex],

      bottomNavigationBar: Container(

        // decoration: BoxDecoration(

        //   gradient: LinearGradient(

        //     colors: [

        //       Color(0xffF8B200).withOpacity(0.75),

        //       Color(0xffF8B200).withOpacity(0.75),

        //       Color(0xff853599).withOpacity(0.64),

        //       Color(0xff853599).withOpacity(0.64),

        //     ],

        //   ),

        // ),

        child: BottomNavigationBar(

          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.0),

          onTap: onTappedBar,

          elevation: 0.0,

          currentIndex: _currentIndex,

          items: [

            BottomNavigationBarItem(

              icon: Icon(

                Icons.home,

                color: Colors.red,

              ),

              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,

              label: ('Home'),

            ),

            BottomNavigationBarItem(

              icon: Icon(Icons.queue_music_outlined, color: Colors.blue),

              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,

              label: ('My Music'),

            ),

            BottomNavigationBarItem(

              icon: Icon(Icons.music_note_outlined, color: Colors.yellow),

              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,

              label: ('Music Queue'),

            ),

            BottomNavigationBarItem(

              icon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.grey),

              label: ('My Profile'),

              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent
```

I'm learning flutter i can do small tiny mistakes also.

Comment: Can you add the code where you used image

Comment: return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: ExactAssetImage(
            'images/home_backgr.png',
          ),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
          body: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Stack(
                children: [

Comment: See this image " https://ibb.co/fS1xqH4 ". The image (Widget) behind the BottomNavigationBar is not visible. Only the background is visible and that's Static too...

Answer (score 0):

If you give scaffold to transparent colour so it shows black colour so if you don't give scaffold background colour you will get white by default in bottom NavigationBar and if you want another colour set scaffold colour as you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap `Container` over the `Scaffold` and set the background to `Container` and set `transparent` to `Scaffold` and `BottomNavigationBar`.
Remove `extendBody` from `Scaffold`.

Code should look like as following..

```
Contatiner(
  //Use decoration or color to set the background.
  color: Colors.pink[900],//As your wish
  child: Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
     //extendBody: true,
     ....
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        ....
        )
    )
)
```